# Method to "remember" past entries

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox, stack, queue

Part of an application I'm building in VB has terminal functionality, and I'd like to add functionality to it so it remembers past commands in chronological order, similarly to how a windosw terminal works.

In short I'd like you to be able to press the up arrow when the text area is focused and be able to cycle through a list of commands that were entered previously.

I had two ideas for how to do this:

1. A combobox that, when you hit enter, reads whatever is in combobox.text, whether that be a newly entered command or an old one that was selected. Then add that command to the items of the combobox so you could scroll up and find it again.
2. Simply a textbox that, when the up arrow is pressed, cycles through some stored queue and sets the text accordingly. This would requires a second queue to remember the cycled through commands and replace them, correct?

Are there any built-in structures of Visual Basic that would be better for this, or is there some better way of doing it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for something like a Most Recently Used List.

You idea for the `ComboBox` is probably generally the right thing to do.  To do what you suggest with a `TextBox` would largely result in...a `ComboBox`.

Considerations:

- Is it is case sensitive?  Does `FooBar` match `fooBar`?
- A Stack (or Queue) is not the right tool for this because if they use something from index 4 in the list, there is no easy way to move that item from #4 to #1.
- To use this with a `ComboBox` as the UI picker, you want to use something that will work as a binding source.

Here is a nascent MRU class:

```
Public Class MRUList

    Private myList As BindingList(Of String)

    Public ReadOnly Property DataList As BindingList(Of String)
        Get
            Return myList '.Select(Function(f) f.Value).ToList
        End Get
    End Property

    Private myCapacity As Integer

    Public Sub New(capacity As Integer)
        myCapacity = capacity
        myList = New BindingList(Of String)
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub Add(item As String)

        Dim ndx As Integer = IndexOfKey(item)

        If ndx >= 0 Then
            myList.RemoveAt(ndx)
        End If

        myList.Insert(0, item)

        If myList.Count > myCapacity Then
            myList.RemoveAt(myList.Count - 1)
        End If
    End Sub

    ' case insensitive search
    Private Function IndexOfKey(s As String) As Integer

        Return myList.ToList.FindIndex(Function(f) f.Equals(s,
                   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))

    End Function

End Class
```

- When they pick an existing item, it moves from whence it was to the top of the list.
- It is case insensitive, "Able" matches "ABLE".  But it is case-aware: if/when they *type* an item again, it uses the new casing.  So if "ZIggy" is in the list at slot 3, if they type in "Ziggy" correctly, they old one is removed and the new one used.
- There is a capacity limiter so you wont get absurdly long lists.  When the lists gets too long, old items are dropped.
- It is built from a `BindingList(Of String)` so that you can bind it to a `Listbox` or `ComboBox`.

The List management is pretty wasteful under the hood.  Each time we insert a new item at `myList(0)` .NET has to shift and jigger the underlying array around.  The ideal collection type would be a `LinkedList`, but that wont work as a binding source and I dont suspect you will have 1000s of items being stored.

#### Usage:

```
Private myMRU As New MRUList(8)
...
' bind to CBO in form_load:
cboMRU.DataSource = myMRU.DataList
```

As things are added to the list they will automatically appear in the list.  When the user makes a selection

```
Private Sub cboMRU_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboMRU.Leave
    If cboMRU.Text.Length = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Dim thisCmd As String = cboMRU.Text
    myMRU.Add(thisCmd)
    cboMRU.Text = ""

End Sub
```

I used the `Leave` event because they can pick from the list *or* select an item from the list.  You code doesn't need to do anything as far as checking for new vs existing items, the `Add` method does that for you.

[image]

On the left, I entered 4 items, `Delta` being the last one.  Next, I typed in `Able` correctly.  The class removed the old one and floated the new one to the top as the MRU with the new spelling.

Since these mean something to your code, use `thisCmd` in the event for whatever they are.  For more complex things, perhaps where what they type is just a key or token for something else, use a `BindingList(of TokenItem)` in the `MRU` Class

Comment: To answers your considerations, no, they are not case sensitive, so your solution is fitting, and yes I understand now why stacks and queues aren't ideal in this scenario. And thanks for a new word! "nascent"

I will work on implementing this today, thanks for your help! I knew there must be some structure similar to BindingSource but didn't know what it was. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The 'BindingList' allows data added to show up in the CBO without any extra steps.  The class needs a `Clear` method, probably a `Count` function.  `Contains` might be nice too.

Comment: One more comment: Can you explain the line `Return myList.ToList.FindIndex(Function(f) f.Equals(s,
                   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`? I don't have a great depth of experience in VB and haven't seen the `Function` keyword used this way.
The reason I ask is because, even though I didn't mention it, I do need to distinguigh between text with symbols. For example, `text` vs `text:` should be distinguishable. At the moment, the combobox will register them as separate items but `cmb.Text` will always return whichever is entered first. Is there other way of comparing?

Comment: Never mind, I've realized that I can just save `cmb.Text` in a variable and use that, rather than referencing `cmb.Text` itself after manipulating the BindingList. Thanks for all the help! Edit: Just to be clear, what I was doing was adding the command to the list, and then referencing cmb.Text. If I do the same thing in opposite order it function correctly.

Comment: The BindingList doesnt have an Index method, so ToList converts to a `List<T>` which does, then the Function is what does the case insensitive comparison to see if ABLE matches Able.  The answer covers using the unaltered version (`thisCmd`)

Answer (score 0):

Better than a queue would be an array. The queue allow only sequential access, and after you dequeue it, the object you dequeue get "lost". If you want save it and have also in future session, you can use a file, such cookie or what I prefere, also because prepare the ground for future expansions, an embedded database, such sqlite or firebird. The second one is an incredible powerful database, that allow if you want to get a server, a powerful server

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't plan on saving the commands beyond the .exe's running so saving it to a file isn't necessary. An array would certainly get the job done, but is it efficient enough? My mind jumped to a stack ( I should've said stack earlier, not queue) because of the nature of how it is stored (most recently stored = most easily accessible), and like I said I could easily use two data structures to keep track of popped items. And I'm always worried about having a dynamically sized array. I have no idea how many commands I will ahve to store.

Comment: The arrays are the most efficient data structure. Stack and queue are for situations. When you really need a sequential access and it is better don't save the info. Such the calls to a server, the function call stack, the branch of a tree when you make a traversal. But if you have to remember all the things, you need to store them. Array is the better solution.

Comment: You're right, the way stacks and queues function aren't ideal for this scenario. I guess I was giving simplicity too much credit for being efficient whereas the structure wasn't fitting. Thanks for your input.